# Outlook 2010 Security Settings and Hardening

Tags: security, outlook, outlook-2010, hardening

We are looking at rolling out Outlook 2010 in the near future.  What recommendations, guides, settings, tools, etc. would you recommend to secure and harden the installation and usage of Outlook 2010?  What works and what does not work?

Note: I am not looking for the pros and cons of using Outlook, just how to secure it and what settings should been toggled or implemented.

Note 2:  This would be for average users in a large enterprise setting for daily e-mail use with the possibility in the future of using personal digital certificates.  Hardening it from what would be answered the same way that we would harden the base operating system.

Comment: Secure and harden it in what way? Against what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends to some extent on what your requirements are, but Outlook is pretty secure out of the box these days. It renders messages in a sandbox, it doesn't download embedded images automatically, there are a number of phishing warnings it pops based on content of messages.